# Sum the value from json array of object

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json

```
{ "Chemistry - II": [ { "id": "9", "title": "Solid State", "quecount": 12 }, { "id": "10", "title": "Solutions", "quecount": 9 }, { "id": "11", "title": "Electrochemistry", "quecount": 8 }, { "id": "6", "title": "d and f- Block elements", "quecount": 42 } ], "Physics": [ { "id": "3", "title": "Circular Motion", "quecount": 5 } ] }
```

I am trying to sum the "quecount" but fail to get the result

```
$scope.chlist;
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.chlist.length; i++) 
    {  
        total += $scope.chlist[i].quecount; 
    }

    $scope.totque = total;
```

Help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you..

Comment: You need total for chemistry and physics separately or total of all ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()` and `Array.prototype.reduce()`

```js
let chlist = {
  "Chemistry - II": [{
    "id": "9",
    "title": "Solid State",
    "quecount": 12
  }, {
    "id": "10",
    "title": "Solutions",
    "quecount": 9
  }, {
    "id": "11",
    "title": "Electrochemistry",
    "quecount": 8
  }, {
    "id": "6",
    "title": "d and f- Block elements",
    "quecount": 42
  }],
  "Physics": [{
    "id": "3",
    "title": "Circular Motion",
    "quecount": 5
  }]
};

Object.values(chlist).forEach(function(v){
  console.log(v.map(o => o.quecount).reduce((a,b) => a + b));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `angular.forEach` to loop over all the `groups` (like : Chemistry - II), for each group you want to count the `quecount`.

**On your controller:**

```
$scope.chlist = {
    "Chemistry - II": [{
      "id": "9",
      "title": "Solid State",
      "quecount": 12
    }, {
      "id": "10",
      "title": "Solutions",
      "quecount": 9
    }, {
      "id": "11",
      "title": "Electrochemistry",
      "quecount": 8
    }, {
      "id": "6",
      "title": "d and f- Block elements",
      "quecount": 42
    }],
    "Physics": [{
      "id": "3",
      "title": "Circular Motion",
      "quecount": 5
    }]
 }

 var total = 0;
 angular.forEach($scope.chlist, function(value, key) {
   angular.forEach(value, function(item) {
     total += item.quecount;
    });
 });

 $scope.totque = total;
```

[See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kt883pf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < $scope.chlist["Chemistry - II"].length; i++) {  
    total += $scope.chlist["Chemistry - II"][i].quecount;
}
```

Try to add key - "Chemistry - II"

Comment: @PrashantFepale updated code, added key for both, "for" and "total"

Answer (score 0):

```
var o = { "Chemistry - II": [ { "id": "9", "title": "Solid State", "quecount": 12 }, { "id": "10", "title": "Solutions", "quecount": 9 }, { "id": "11", "title": "Electrochemistry", "quecount": 8 }, { "id": "6", "title": "d and f- Block elements", "quecount": 42 } ], "Physics": [ { "id": "3", "title": "Circular Motion", "quecount": 5 } ] };

var total = 0;
for(var p in o) {
   if( Array.isArray(o[p]) ) {
      total = o[p].reduce((function(v, item) {
        return v + item.quecount;
      }, total);
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    
    $scope.jsonObj = {
 "Chemistry - II": [{
  "id": "9",
  "title": "Solid State",
  "quecount": 12
 }, {
  "id": "10",
  "title": "Solutions",
  "quecount": 9
 }, {
  "id": "11",
  "title": "Electrochemistry",
  "quecount": 8
 }, {
  "id": "6",
  "title": "d and f- Block elements",
  "quecount": 42
 }],
 "Physics": [{
  "id": "3",
  "title": "Circular Motion",
  "quecount": 5
 }]
};
    var chemistryQuecount = 0;
    var physicsQuecount = 0;
    for (var i in $scope.jsonObj) {
      if(i == 'Chemistry - II') {
        for(var j in $scope.jsonObj[i]) {
          chemistryQuecount += $scope.jsonObj[i][j].quecount;
        }
      }
      if(i == 'Physics') {
        for(var j in $scope.jsonObj[i]) {
          physicsQuecount += $scope.jsonObj[i][j].quecount;
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(chemistryQuecount);
    console.log(physicsQuecount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
</div>
```